# how to get some text from text_field in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNFm6.png)

here is the text that I will be input in text_field
www.sketchfab.com/models/6ae7a1905b0f48aab0b4145d9333751b

but the result that I want to get after save just only
6ae7a1905b0f48aab0b4145d9333751b

so what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

in you model create a `before_validation` callback

Suppose class name is Image and field name is `description`

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :fetch_correct_descripton

  private
    def fetch_correct_descripton
      self.description = description.to_s.split('/').last
    end
end
```

Comment: @khdeep glad to help you.
If it's working it would be really helpful if you can accept this answer so that it can be easier for others with the same issue to know that this will solve their purpose.